# aws how to manage iam ssh access to ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am trying to follow this guid but it looks like the stack may be missing some information. I am trying to create this in eu-west-2

https://cloudonaut.io/manage-aws-ec2-ssh-access-with-iam/

It errors with `“Template validation error: Template error: Unable to get mapping for RegionMap::eu-west-2::AMI”`

**UPDATE**

should the region map look like this?

```
Mappings:
  RegionMap:
    'eu-west-2':
      AMI: 'ami-098828924dc89ea4a'
```

I still get error `Template error: Unable to get mapping for RegionMap::eu-west-2::AMI`

**UPDATE 2**

I shortened the AMI id which let me go to create but now during creation i get an error

`The image id '[ami-09882892]' does not exist (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidAMIID.NotFound; Request ID: 63e7da3e-ac16-4382-91a2-5ea365d63fec; Proxy: null)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below AMI is what you should be using, update the CFT and use that

```
aws ssm get-parameter --name /aws/service/ami-amazon-linux-latest/amzn2-ami-hvm-x86_64-gp2 --region eu-west-2

{
    "Parameter": {
        "Name": "/aws/service/ami-amazon-linux-latest/amzn2-ami-hvm-x86_64-gp2",
        "Type": "String",
        "Value": "ami-098828924dc89ea4a",
        "Version": 38,
        "LastModifiedDate": "2021-01-27T07:52:29.948000+05:30",
        "ARN": "arn:aws:ssm:eu-west-2::parameter/aws/service/ami-amazon-linux-latest/amzn2-ami-hvm-x86_64-gp2",
        "DataType": "text"
    }
}
```

To get the list of latest Amazon Linux AMIs, use the below ssm CLI

```
aws ssm get-parameters-by-path --path /aws/service/ami-amazon-linux-latest --query "Parameters[].Name" --region eu-west-2
    [
        "/aws/service/ami-amazon-linux-latest/amzn-ami-hvm-x86_64-ebs",
        "/aws/service/ami-amazon-linux-latest/amzn-ami-hvm-x86_64-gp2",
        "/aws/service/ami-amazon-linux-latest/amzn-ami-hvm-x86_64-s3",
        "/aws/service/ami-amazon-linux-latest/amzn-ami-minimal-hvm-x86_64-ebs",
        "/aws/service/ami-amazon-linux-latest/amzn-ami-minimal-hvm-x86_64-s3",
        "/aws/service/ami-amazon-linux-latest/amzn2-ami-hvm-arm64-gp2",
        "/aws/service/ami-amazon-linux-latest/amzn2-ami-hvm-x86_64-ebs",
        "/aws/service/ami-amazon-linux-latest/amzn2-ami-hvm-x86_64-gp2",
        "/aws/service/ami-amazon-linux-latest/amzn2-ami-minimal-hvm-arm64-ebs",
        "/aws/service/ami-amazon-linux-latest/amzn2-ami-minimal-hvm-x86_64-ebs"
    ]
```

Comment: Your first update should work, likely indentation issue.
If not, try hardcoding the AMI Id directly here at line # 169. Instead of below line
      ImageId: !FindInMap [RegionMap, !Ref 'AWS::Region', AMI]
use       ImageId: ami-098828924dc89ea4a

Answer (score 0):

That blog is almost 5 years old, `eu-west-2` didn't exist back then, it was launched publicly in December 2016 and the blog is from April 2016.

According to the template that's linked, these are the supported regions:

```yaml
Mappings:
  RegionMap:
    'ap-south-1':
      AMI: 'ami-cacbbea5'
    'eu-west-1':
      AMI: 'ami-d41d58a7'
    'ap-northeast-2':
      AMI: 'ami-a04297ce'
    'ap-northeast-1':
      AMI: 'ami-1a15c77b'
    'sa-east-1':
      AMI: 'ami-b777e4db'
    'ap-southeast-1':
      AMI: 'ami-7243e611'
    'ap-southeast-2':
      AMI: 'ami-55d4e436'
    'eu-central-1':
      AMI: 'ami-0044b96f'
    'us-east-1':
      AMI: 'ami-c481fad3'
    'us-east-2':
      AMI: 'ami-71ca9114'
    'us-west-1':
      AMI: 'ami-de347abe'
    'us-west-2':
      AMI: 'ami-b04e92d0'
```

I'd be very careful about using this template as the AMIs used here are probably completely out of date.

Comment: I am only using eu-west-2. How would I get an update list like that?